# How to modify json response?

Tags: java, json, api, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm having trouble filtering my database query result in the API.

Maybe I'll introduce my code first and then explain what I mean.

```
    @Entity
    @Validated
    public class Ksiazka {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idKsiazka;
    private int idKategoria;
    private String isbn;
    @JsonView(DoubleName.class)
    private String tytul;
    @JsonView(DoubleName.class)
    private String autor;
    private int stron;
    private String wydawnictwo;
    private int rokWydania;
    private String opis;

    public Ksiazka(){ }

    public Ksiazka(int idKsiazka, int idKategoria, String isbn, String tytul, String autor, int stron, String wydawnictwo, int rokWydania, String opis) {
        this.idKsiazka = idKsiazka;
        this.idKategoria = idKategoria;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.tytul = tytul;
        this.autor = autor;
        this.stron = stron;
        this.wydawnictwo = wydawnictwo;
        this.rokWydania = rokWydania;
        this.opis = opis;
    }

    public int getIdKsiazka() {
        return idKsiazka;
    }

    public void setIdKsiazka(int idKsiazka) {
        this.idKsiazka = idKsiazka;
    }

    public int getIdKategoria() {
        return idKategoria;
    }

    public void setIdKategoria(int idKategoria) {
        this.idKategoria = idKategoria;
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public String getTytul() {
        return tytul;
    }

    public void setTytul(String tytul) {
        this.tytul = tytul;
    }

    public String getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }

    public void setAutor(String autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    public int getStron() {
        return stron;
    }

    public void setStron(int stron) {
        this.stron = stron;
    }

    public String getWydawnictwo() {
        return wydawnictwo;
    }

    public void setWydawnictwo(String wydawnictwo) {
        this.wydawnictwo = wydawnictwo;
    }

    public int getRokWydania() {
        return rokWydania;
    }

    public void setRokWydania(int rokWydania) {
        this.rokWydania = rokWydania;
    }

    public String getOpis() {
        return opis;
    }

    public void setOpis(String opis) {
        this.opis = opis;
    }
}
```

---

```
@JsonView(DoubleName.class)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/getAll")
public List<Ksiazka> find(@RequestParam("id") int id){
    List<String> autor = ksiazkaRepo.findInfoById(id); // get result as as  list
    List<Ksiazka> ksiazkaList = new ArrayList<>(); // create list from Ksiazka
    for (String autors : autor) { // returned result you can loop
        Ksiazka ksiazka = new Ksiazka(); // create Object to Ksiazka
        ksiazka.setAutor(autors);
        ksiazkaList.add(ksiazka); //add created object to List
    }
    return ksiazkaList; // return your list
}
```

---

```
@Repository
public interface KsiazkaRepo extends JpaRepository<Ksiazka, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT ksiazka.tytul, ksiazka.autor FROM IEci8d0gZc.ksiazka WHERE ksiazka.rok_wydania = :id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<String> findInfoById(@Param("id") int id); // here you

}
```

---

[image]

---

Getting to the point.

By creating such a query, for example, "rok_wydania" = 2014, you get the result in the form:

```
[
    {
        "tytul": null,
        "autor": "Język C++. Kompendium wiedzy,Bjarne Stroustrup"
    },
    {
        "tytul": null,
        "autor": "Kali Linux. Testy penetracyjne,Joseph Muniz, Aamir Lakhani"
    },
    {
        "tytul": null,
        "autor": "Praca z zastanym kodem. Najlepsze techniki,Michael Feathers"
    },
    {
        "tytul": null,
        "autor": "Tajemnice JavaScriptu. Podręcznik ninja,John Resig, Bear Bibeault"
    },
    {
        "tytul": null,
        "autor": "Java EE 6. Tworzenie aplikacji w NetBeans 7,David R. Heffelfinger"
    },
    {
        "tytul": null,
        "autor": "Projektowanie stron internetowych. Przewodnik dla początkujących webmasterów po HTML5, CSS3 i grafice. Wydanie IV,Jennifer Niederst Robbins"
    }
]
```

---

Everything is cool, because it extracts the data I need from databases, but the answer in JSON is not what I would like.
How to check if the answer is divided into 2. In the sense that the title "title" falls into the place and the author falls accordingly to the place "author".
To make it look something like this:

```
[
    {
        "tytul": "Język C++. Kompendium wiedzy",
        "autor": ",Bjarne Stroustrup"
    },
    {
        "tytul": "Kali Linux. Testy penetracyjne",
        "autor": "Joseph Muniz, Aamir Lakhani"
    },
    {
        "tytul": "Praca z zastanym kodem. Najlepsze techniki",
        "autor": "Michael Feathers"
    },
    {
        "tytul": "Tajemnice JavaScriptu. Podręcznik ninja",
        "autor": "John Resig, Bear Bibeault"
    },
    {
        "tytul": "Java EE 6. Tworzenie aplikacji w NetBeans 7",
        "autor": "David R. Heffelfinger"
    },
    {
        "tytul": "Projektowanie stron internetowych. Przewodnik dla początkujących webmasterów po HTML5, CSS3 i grafice. Wydanie IV",
        "autor": "Jennifer Niederst Robbins"
    }
]
```

---

Any ideas what should be changed? :D
Thanks,
SM

Comment: Please show `findTitleById` method

Comment: Or, where are you actually using `findInfoById`?

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I put wrong method there. UPDATED

Comment: Okay, so you do `SELECT ksiazka.tytul, ksiazka.autor`, which is 2 strings, then there are multiple `rok_wydania`, so how are you expecting to get both columns of info?

Answer (score 0):

Try to find your entity (ksiazka) by id.

```
Optional<Ksiazka> maybeKsiazka = Optional.ofNullable(ksiazkaRepo.findOne(id));
if (maybeKsiazka.isPresent() {
     return maybeKsiazka.get();
}
```

If you want to do it in separate query you can do query for tytul some like below

```
@Query(value = "SELECT k.tytul FROM Ksiazka k WHERE k.idKsiazka= :id")
Optional<String> findTytulById(@Param("id") int id);
```

Comment: Note: the result in the question is a list, not a single object

Comment: @cricket_007 you're right ... I misunderstood what the variable "id" means in this case

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you never set the title in the loop, so it's null

To illustrate,

```
List<String> autors = ksiazkaRepo.findInfoById(id);

List<Ksiazka> ksiazkaList = new ArrayList<>(); 
for (String a : autors) { 
    Ksiazka ksiazka = new Ksiazka();
    ksiazka.setAutor(a);
    ksiazka.setTitle("you're missing this data from the query result");
    ksiazkaList.add(ksiazka);
}
```

You need to adjust the return type of the findInfo method to be a class with two fields that match the columns being selected if that's all you want displayed. Otherwise, I'm not sure I understand why returning a list of Ksiazka wouldn't show all the other null fields in the JSON

I presume that's what your `DoubleName` class is for? If so, you'd do

```
List<DoubleName> info = ksiazkaRepo.findInfoById(id);

List<Ksiazka> ksiazkaList = new ArrayList<>(); 
for (DoubleName d : info) { 
   ...
```